# Error Compiling Monero from Source [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, build

Encountered the following error attempting to compile monero from source following this guide: https://github.com/moneroexamples/monero-compilation#example-compilation-of-monero-on-ubuntu-1804. Building on Ubuntu in a VM on windows

[image: Error log]

The error always occurred when it reaches the core_rpc_server. Sometimes it hangs my VM entirely, sometimes it manages to exit with the above error code. Any solutions? Can't use cli binary because I need to use the following library: https://github.com/moneroexamples/transactions-export

Comment: How much memory available, and what are your build steps? Are you able to build from https://github.com/monero-project/monero ?

Comment: 6.8 GB available. Followed the exact steps from https://github.com/moneroexamples/monero-compilation#example-compilation-of-monero-on-ubuntu-1804. No, I get the same error too.

Comment: If you were refering to RAM, it was 2GB. I increased ram allocated to 8gb and restarted, still trying.

Comment: Update: successfully compiled Monero after bumping RAM to 8GB. Looks like lack of RAM was causing  GCC to crash. Thanks for the prompt.

Comment: Yes. Minimum 2GB RAM per thread.

Answer (score 1):

`c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus` usually means running out of memory.

You can confirm by running `sudo dmesg` right after the error, and looking for a message like:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 23747 (cc1plus) score 15 or sacrifice child
Killed process 23747, UID 2243, (cc1plus) total-vm:214456kB, anon-rss:178936kB, file-rss:5908kB
```

Two things to try:

1. If you're running with a `-j#` flag (like `-j8`), that will use 8 cores - try using `-j1` instead (will be a bit slower)
2. Create a swap file (this uses your disk as extra RAM):

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=64M count=128
$ sudo mkswap /swapfile
$ sudo swapon /swapfile
```

<sup>(These particular commands add 64M * 128 = 8GB of new "RAM" - Adjust as needed)</sup>